# DAX expression to calculate running total from specific point

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have got a calculated table "CountryMonth" which lists country and months. For a country there can exist value represented by "Selected" measure (with some value > 0). There is also a column "order" to specify order of months from April to March.

**The expected is to create new measure on "CountryMonth":**
when Start Point is 10% and for a Country (like Afghanistan on a screenshot) the month June is selected then for all previous months (May, April) value of new Measure must be 0 %. The June must be set as 10% and all next months up to the end of FY (March) must be increased by 3%.

If month is not selected for a country then all country months should be set as 0%.

[image]

if on screenshot we would have the start point set to 0% and June would be the set for Afghanistan then the expected result should be:

March - 0%

April - 0%

May - 0%

June -0 %

July - 3%

August - 6 % etc

in case of 50%

March - 0%

April - 0%

May - 0%

June -50 %

July - 53%

August 56% etc

Comment: So the requirement is from the row where value > 0 then from that row 3 need to be added, correct?

Comment: @Siva - the calculation should start from row where "Selected" is not blank - on screen it should start from Afghanistan - June and for Albania from May

Comment: Ok so in the new calculated column all rows above "Selected not blank" should be "0" and rows below should be incremented by "3", correct?

Comment: @Siva - All which are above selected (by Order) should have the value incremented by 3% otherwise when below should be always 0%. Example: Afghanistan/June is "selected" and initial value is 10% so Afghanistan/July should be 13%, Afghanistan/August 16% etc